# How do i set a specific route on href with .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How do i set in the razor page, what's the route will be called on href, using tag helpers?

My Controller, named TestController:

```
[Route("A/B/C",Name = "Route_1")]
[Route("A/B/C/{id?}",Name = "Route_2")]
[Route("A/B/C/D/{id?}",Name = "Route_3")]
public IActionResult TestAction(string id = null)
{
    ... 
}
```

The view:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
   style="margin-bottom:4px;"
   asp-controller="TestController"
   asp-action="TestAction"
   asp-route-id="@Model.Id">
    Click button
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `asp-route` for named routes:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right"
   style="margin-bottom:4px;"
   asp-route="Route_3"
   asp-route-id="@Model.Id">
    Click button
</a>
```

Comment: Thank's. Worked perfectly.